# Git Bash Phonegap commands not found

Tags: git, nodes, phonegap

I'm recently experimenting with Git Bash Phonegap commands. I had installed Nodes, Git Bash and Phonegap via the Git Bash terminal and had no problems executing commands in the past, however recently I tried uninstalling and reinstalling (Nodes, Git Bash, Phonegap), I now can't seem to implement any Phonegap commands in Gitbash (this is the same if I install Cordova) - I know the packages are added, but I'm at a loss as to why a simple command like `phonegap --version` (or --v) gives me back a '**bash: phonegap: command not found**'. Searching for answers on Stackoverflow I see that there is a usr/local/lib directory and the settings can be changed from 'everyone:No Access' to 'everyone: Read only' - but this is on a Mac - could it be a permissions setting in Windows? It worked before this is really frustrating just to implement the Gitbash terminal.
Thanks
Tim

Comment: What is the actual error you have?

Comment: Thank you so much. The error message reads  **bash: phonegap: command not found** -- but again, it seems to be for any associated phonegap command line (phonegap --v, phonegap serve, etc)

Comment: Please check node is installed `npm-v` and reinstall phonegap using the global flag `npm i -g phonegap`

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/ check their instructions as well

Comment: I can do Phonegap commands now in nodes.js for some reason, I used to be able to do this in Git Bash, it's so weird. I was thinking maybe the folder location has to be similar - as I used nodes.js to install phonegap, perhaps git bash is somehow not associated? Anyhow, I am using nodes.js with the phonegap commands, when I was using git bash before - it must be something I'm overlooking. Any help would be appreciated.